# SqlDataAdapter Fill returns exception

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2008-r2, .net-3.5

Server-side:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[POS_STORED_OBJECTS_GET_SP]
    @STORE_ID nvarchar(8)
    ,@TERMINAL_ID nvarchar(8)
    ,@OBJECT_ID bigint
AS
```

Client-side:

```cs
SqlParameter storeID = new SqlParameter("@STORE_ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
storeID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
storeID.Value = Properties.storeId;
SqlParameter termanalID = new SqlParameter("@TERMINAL_ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
termanalID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
termanalID.Value = null;
SqlParameter objectID = new SqlParameter("@OBJECT_ID", SqlDbType.BigInt);
objectID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
objectID.Value = null;  

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.сonnectionString);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("POS_STORED_OBJECTS_GET_SP", connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.Add(storeID);
command.Parameters.Add(termanalID);
command.Parameters.Add(objectID);  

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = command;  

DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(dataSet);
```

Finally, **adapter.Fill** throwing an exception:

> Procedure or function 'POS_STORED_OBJECTS_GET_SP' expects parameter
>   '@TERMINAL_ID', which was not supplied

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: provide `DBNull.Value` for `TERMINAL_ID` and 0 for `@OBJECT_ID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `null` for the parameter value, try to use `System.DBNull.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `termanalID.Value = DBNull.Value` instead of null.

`DBNull.Value` used to send a `NULL` value as the value of the parameter.

You can use `null` or do not set `Value` property to use the default value for the parameter, but since you haven't specified any default values in your stored procedure - in your particular case it has no sense.

The same story with `objectID` parameter.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could also set some parameters default value to null on the database side. This way you won't have to create useless parameters on client side.

Server side:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[POS_STORED_OBJECTS_GET_SP]
    @STORE_ID nvarchar(8)
    ,@TERMINAL_ID nvarchar(8) = null
    ,@OBJECT_ID bigint = null
    AS
```

Client side:

```
SqlParameter storeID = new SqlParameter("@STORE_ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
storeID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
storeID.Value = Properties.storeId;

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.сonnectionString);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("POS_STORED_OBJECTS_GET_SP", connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.Add(storeID);

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = command;  

DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(dataSet);
```